# abstract classes in struts2 forms

Tags: struts2

I want to have a form that creates one of several subclasses in a type hierarchy. Say it's AbstractPerson with the subclasses Employee and Visitor.

Can I do that with a single Action / REST-Controller Bean?

Usually I use the form-ids smart, so it assigns values directly to the setters of my Action.
So if I have a member like

```
AbstractPerson member;
```

I would try to use a form with an input field called "member.name".

However, struts must create an instance of AbstractPerson first - and it can't because it's abstract! It would be very cool if I could give struts2 a hint that it should actually create a Empolyee or Visitor object (depending on the form content). Is that or sth similar possible?

Cheers!

Comment: Take a look at the [type conversion](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/type-conversion.html) docs.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to something I've done recently to access Entity classes via a small set of crud actions. That is a handful of crud actions allow you to operate on all the entity classes within a certain package. You should be able to apply this strategy to your Employee and Visitor classes.

How it works in a nutshell:

1) You need to specify in either the namespace or the action name the name of the class that should be created.

2) You use struts2s prepareable interface to create a model. (Reflectively create the class determined from step 1.

3) Use the model driven interface, which returns the object defined in step 2. This way that object is at the top of the stack and you can simply say "name" and know that it is the name attribute of the Class determined in step 1. You could avoid this step but it isn't as pretty.

Now there is a small glitch in doing this, you'll find that to perform the above three steps you'll need a custom stack, a "staticParams-prepare-params" stack.

First an example and then a definition of that stack to make this work, please let me know if you have any questions:

```
package com.quaternion.demo.action.crud;

import com.quaternion.demo.orm.ActionValidateable;
import com.quaternion.demo.service.CrudService;
import com.quaternion.demo.util.ActionUtils;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Preparable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ParentPackage;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

// Adds a new record to the database
@ParentPackage("staticParams-prepare-parms")
@Namespace("/crud/{entityName}")
@Result(type = "kjson") //TODO: could rid of this line by setting the result as the default for the package
public class AddAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable, ModelDriven {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AddAction.class.getName());
    @Autowired
    private CrudService crudService;
    private String entityName; 
    private Object entityModel; 
    private Map jsonModel = new HashMap(); //for output, return the newly created object
    private Class clazz;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        log.log(Level.INFO, "In execute entityName is set with {0}", entityName);
        //If an id is passed in it will merge the object with that id, null will be used for unset attributes
        String status = SUCCESS;
        boolean error = false;
        Object entity = null;
        try { 
            entity = crudService.create(clazz, entityModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = true;
            status = ERROR;
            jsonModel.put("message", e.getMessage());
        }
        if (error == false) {
            jsonModel.put("entity", entity);
        }
        jsonModel.put("status", status);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Object getEntityModel() {
        return entityModel;
    }

    public void setEntityModel(Object entityModel) {
        this.entityModel = entityModel;
    }

    public Object getJsonModel() {
        return jsonModel;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getModel() {
        return this.entityModel;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        log.log(Level.INFO, "In prepare entityName is set with {0}", entityName);
        clazz = ActionUtils.initClazz(entityName);
        entityModel = clazz.newInstance();
    }

    public String getEntityName() {
        return entityName;
    }

    public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
        this.entityName = entityName;
    }

    //TODO: validation would be a good idea can't implement in this class need to delegate
    //if entity implements a validate method, this validate should
    //call that validate
    @Override
    public void validate(){
        if (entityModel instanceof ActionValidateable){
            ((ActionValidateable)entityModel).validate(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a definition for the stack:

```
<package name="staticParams-prepare-parms" extends="struts-default">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="kjson" default="true" class="com.quaternion.demo.result.Kjson"/>
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor-stack name="staticParamsPrepareParamsStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="multiselect"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*,^session\..*,^request\..*,^application\..*,^servlet(Request|Response)\..*,parameters\...*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="staticParamsPrepareParamsStack"/>
</package>
```

You might wonder what the kjson result type is. I was feeling challenged by the struts2-json plugin on several other actions. I created a generic paging and read actions, "flexjson" does not serialize collections by default, which prevents lazy loading issue (well in the case the collections were not loaded which will always be the case with these simple services) so kjson is just a result type which returns json using flexjson.

Comment: +1  The lazy loading could be prevented via `excludeProperties`.

Comment: Nice idea with the custom stack!

Comment: @RomanC but what properties do I exclude when the entity class is determined at run time via the namespace parameter?

Comment: @Quaternion in this case will be better to put JSON annotation on the property.

Comment: What property? The model is determined at run time!