# How to convert a List that its element's class type is not clear in Struts 2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, converters

Does anybody know how to handle this kinda of case in Struts 2 without using any custom converter.

My model definition

1.`Booking`

```
public class Booking extends BaseModel{
    private String bookingNo;
    .....
    private List<Part>parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
    private List <? extends ToDoItem>toDoItems = new ArrayList< ToDoItem>();
    ....
}
```

2.`ToDoItem`

```
public class ToDoItem extends BaseModel{
    private Integer sequence;
    private String bookingNo;
    private String serviceCode;...
```

3.Specified todoitem that inherited from ToDoItem
e.g PDAS

```
   public class PDAS extends ToDoItem{
      private Date estPickupTime;
      private Date actPickupTime;
      private Date estArriAtWarehouseTime;
      private Date actArriAtWarehouseTime;...
```

INSP:

```
public class INSP extends ToDoItem{
    private String confirmOk;
    private Date actInspTime;
    private List<BookingItem>bookingItems;.....
```

...(More specified ToDoItem)

Then in html page,The form definition is as following:

PDAS todoitem html

```
<table class="form-table">

  <tr class="row">

    <td class="td-label" colspan="2">

      <s:label key="INSP" cssStyle="color:blue;"/>

    </td>

    <td class="td-label">

      <s:label key="ToDoItem.status"/>

    </td>

    <td class="td-field">

      <s:property value="booking.toDoItems[1].status"></s:property>

    </td>

    <td class="td-field" colspan="2">

      <s:select list="{'PENDING','COMPLETED','EXCEPTION','CANCELLED'}" labelposition="top"/>

    </td>

  </tr>
```

INSP todoitem html

```
  <tr>
    <td class="td-label">

      <s:label key="ToDoItem.assignedBy"/>

    </td>

    <td class="td-field">

      <s:textfield name="booking.toDoItems[1].assignedBy" cssStyle="width:88%;" value="%{#session.user.userName}"
                   readonly="true" cssClass="readonly"></s:textfield>

    </td>

    <td class="td-label">

      <s:label key="ToDoItem.assignedTo"/>

    </td>


    <td class="td-field">


      <s:textfield name="booking.toDoItems[1].assignedTo" cssStyle="width:88%;" value="%{#session.user.userName}"
                   readonly="true" cssClass="readonly"></s:textfield>


    </td>
```

I know the code i pasted in here is a little mass,But please be patient,My problem is when i enter todoitem's fields,e.g PDAS,INSP's field ,then submit the form,the todoitem got in save action is null,e.g when i loop the todoitems and print it in save action,it got following log:

```
22:23:04,923  INFO BookingAction:100 - Start save booking with 
booking:com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking@726dad0
22:23:04,925 DEBUG BookingAction:104 - The todoitem is [null]
22:23:04,926 DEBUG BookingAction:104 - The todoitem is [null]
22:23:04,927 DEBUG BookingAction:104 - The todoitem is [null]
22:23:04,928 DEBUG BookingAction:104 - The todoitem is [null]
```

I know this is because of the Action convert specified todoitem failed,But does anybody could tell me how to fix it?i know maybe i could write a custom converter to convert the List todoitems,But i don't like custom converter,then is there any other way to let struts help me convert these specified ToDoItems?

Comment: ... How on earth could you do it without a custom converter? How would anything know what sub-type to convert an item to unless you tell it?

Comment: If he only has two sub types it would be reasonable to create an action for each... also he could follow the recipe here to dynamically set an appropriate model (useful if there are many potential model classes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712347/abstract-classes-in-struts2-forms/15715329#15715329

Comment: Hello,If i add one custom converter in my  case,is there any thing special?I tried to add one global custom converter yesterday,but it doesn't work,the struts will still use OGNL expression to set the property by itself,it won't call my custom converter,my xwork-conversion.properties is as following: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking=com.chailie.booking.control.help.BookingConverter,Is there any problem for the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

My problem has solved,i just defined an interceptor to instantiate
List toDoItems   with  PDAS,INSP etc,then set it to valuestack. as i have instantiated toDoItem,struts would just use this existing toDoItems direct and won't create it any more,then problem solved